# How to change kubernetes cluster name?

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to kubernetes. The default cluster name is Kubernetes and I want to rename it to something more meaningful.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the name of a Kubernetes cluster by editing the cluster's configuration file, usually located at `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`.

Find the `--cluster-name` flag in the file and replace its current value with the desired name. After making the change, you will need to restart the kube-apiserver service to apply the changes.

Answer (score 0):

To rename a Kubernetes cluster, you need to update the cluster name in the cluster's API server configuration. Here are the steps to do this:

1. Stop the API server:

```bash
kubectl drain <node-name> --ignore-daemonsets
kubectl delete node <node-name>
```

2. Edit the API server configuration file:

```bash
sudo nano /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml
```

3. Locate the following line:

```css
    - --cluster-name=kubernetes
```

4. Change the kubernetes to your desired name, for example:

```bash
    - --cluster-name=my-cluster-name
```

5. Save and close the file.
6. Restart the API server:

```bash
kubectl create -f /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml
```

7. Verify the change by running the following command:

```bash
kubectl config current-context
```

This should show the updated cluster name in the output.

Note: The above steps assume you are running a self-hosted Kubernetes cluster. If you are using a managed Kubernetes service, the steps may differ.